# Kasperky Anti-Banner not included in Kaspersky Endpoint Security?

Tags: kaspersky

Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0 for Windows Workstations includes "Privacy Protection" which includes "Anti-Banner". Kaspersky Endpoint Protection 8 includes URL filtering system.

With the last product, I can block websites which are listed in banner category; so I can simulate "Anti-Banner" module.

The problem is that URL filtering doesn't hide banners, but replaces them with an ugly red warning.

Is there a way to make Kaspersky Endpoint Protection 8 to hide banners?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! The Anti-Banner component has been superseded by Web Control component. You just need to go to the Web Control options and then create a rule to block the category "Banners".